# Update/Insert from CSV to Table

Tags: postgresql

for example i need to export `mytbl` as `csv`

```
    CREATE TABLE public.mytbl
(
   id integer, 
   product character varying(20), 
   patent character varying(50)
) 
WITH (
  OIDS = FALSE
)
;
```

and i use the following query to export the `mytbl` into `csv`

```
copy(select * from mytbl) to 'D:\mytbl.csv' with csv header
```

and using `COPY mytbl FROM 'D:\mytbl.csv' CSV HEADER` this will inserts from `csv`

but i need to delete the existing data in `mytbl` before importing it from `mytbl.csv`,
when i deletes getting error

```
ERROR:  update or delete on table "mytbl" violates foreign key constraint "mytblX_forinkey_productid" on table "mytblX"
```

how to overcome this ?

On `PostgreSQL 9.2`

Comment: You mean the destination database is not Postgresql?

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto both are `PostgreSQL`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your mytblX has a FK to mytbl. Before you can drop your mytbl you should `ALTER TABLE mytblX DROP CONSTRAINT mytblX_forinkey_productid`. Then you can copy the data back in and issue `ALTER TABLE mytblX ADD your_table_constraint`.

Note that FK constraints are based on an index so you should create the appropriate index on the newly copied in data before you recreate the FK constraint. Also note that the new data may not meet the requirements set by mytblX data; i.e. if that references a productid which is not in the data you copy into the database then you will have problems that need to be solved first (usually manually and tediously).

Comment: `ALTER TABLE mytblX ADD your_table_constraint` showing error `ERROR:  syntax error at end of input`  i think this one is correct `ALTER TABLE mytblX  ADD CONSTRAINT mytblX _forinkey_productid FOREIGN KEY (productid) REFERENCES mytblX (productid) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;`

Comment: Yes, there are many options for table constraints and without knowledge of your table structures there was no option for me to come up with the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can set the constraint as deferrable, and then defer it.  This will let you delete the contents of the original table and reload it from the file within a single transaction.  But if the file doesn't contain all the rows it needs to satisfy the constraint, then you will get an error on `COMMIT`.